# Python Generators Vs Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, generator, yield

I have a continuos flow of data, coming from a socket.

I need to operate on them on-the-fly, while other data are still coming.

Is it better to use a yield (generator-like) or a thread ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both work. Both have their problems.

David Beazley talks nicely about the problems of both and illustrates it in this PyCon 2015 talk video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4

Short summary is kind of:

- You can use both generators/co-routines or threads or multiprocessing to do your work
- The Python GIL will bite you for co-routines/threads if anything involves hard computational work in pure Python (C-Extension like numpy can avoid that).
- As long as you mostly do I/O it doesn't matter so much. Threads work better if you have larger chunks of work, co-routines tend work better if you have smaller chunks. If you use pools, e.g. from the futures module, you can tune and change the behaviour a bit.

Pretty hard to say in general what works best, it entirely depends on your workload.

Comment: Thanks fo the answer.
Watching David scripting is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to handle long running networking(socket) operations using threads. This is especially useful if you have any activity to be done in the main thread (or after receiving inputs from sockets).

Generators are generally not used in networking operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need multithreading, if while processing a portion of received data simultaneously try to receive more data. This has nothing to do with yield, as yielding would still block your simultaneous processing while waiting for data to be received.